# Real time face detection OpenCV, Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a basic program for a real time face detection. Here's my code (I am a newbie in OpenCV) :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
name = 'detect'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
while True:
    s, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    #print s
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.imshow(name, img)    
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyWindow("Detect")
        break
```

But when I run this code I get this error :

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line   2482
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mytry.py", line 27, in <module>
cv2.imshow(name, img)    
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

I am a newbie in OpenCV ! Please tell me what is wrong with the code, why does this error arises what changes should I make ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

will draw a rectangle in the image, but the return value will be None, so img changes to None and cannot be drawn.

Try

```
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

Comment: You should also use `cv2.destroyWindow(name)`. Right now the window names don't match, so it doesn't shut down properly.

Comment: @Abe Oh! yes, Thanks, that was a typo. `cv2.destroyWindow(name)` is the right way to do